# run azure pipeline task as per dynamic conditions

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Can we run task of azure pipeline as per dynamic condition?

Actually i want to run some of the task from the listed task, and every time choice of the task to run maybe different as per user requirement.

Comment: Did you refer to the documentation on task conditons?

Comment: @Tabrez Shams Hi ,Tabrez Does my answer meet your need?If you have any question ,please kindly let me know.

Comment: thanks for answering my question. All the stuff you provided I already gone through and still i am unable to find solution of my problem.

Comment: @TabrezShams Basically we could set the conditions for each task, however it's based on the specific requirements, So, could you please share your specific requirements? Just provide a sample scenario, thus we can give help correspondingly.

Comment: @Tabrez Shams How is your issue progressing?Can you provide a sample scenario  to us?

Comment: @Tabrez Shams, Not get your response for several days, would you please share us much more information like Andy's suggestion? So we can follow up and provide the suggestion for you in time.

Answer (score 1):

For your issue,I think you can set conditions through **Control Options** in task to control the run of task. If this does not meet your needs, you can give a specific example, so that I can better understand your request.

Inside the Control Options of each task you can specify the conditions under which the task  will run.

If the built-in conditions don't meet your needs, then you can specify **custom conditions**

[image]

Conditions are written as expressions. The agent evaluates the expression beginning with the innermost function and works its way out. The final result is a boolean value that determines if the task should run or not. See the [expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) topic for a full guide to the syntax.

Here is a [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic) provided some examples,you can refer to it.